# CodeIgniter - database result array but only one row

Tags: php, database, arrays, codeigniter, row

I'm looking for a way to return an array from the database query, but only for the first row. I'd prefer not to use objects..

My current solution:

```
//Gather
$data = $this->db->from('view')->where('alias', $alias)->get()->result_array();

//Collect the first row only
$data = $data[0];
```

Which is pretty ugly to be honest. As said, I'd prefer to not use objects.

Comment: Why don't you want to use objects??

Comment: Use row method. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: Also curious, like @Mischa, why do you shy away from objects? Especially in an MVC framework.

Comment: Objects are ugly? Development is not going to be easy for you...

Comment: ugly why you think so and why you do not want to use objects with an object oriented language?

Comment: @Repox and everyone else: I don't believe that objects are ugly, rather my previous method to only get the first row as an array.

Comment: @Mischa The reason that I ain't using objects here is that the CI Parser Library requires the data to be parsed to be stored in an array. That's the reason, I have nothing against objects :-).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `row()` method instead:

```
$data = $this->db->from('view')->where('alias', $alias)->get()->row();
```

[Oh, you don't want to use objects. `row_array()` then. But consider objects.]

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
$data = $this->db->from('view')->where('alias', $alias)->get()->row_array();
```

This does the same as minitech's answer, only it returns an array (like you want) instead of an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the row_array() function to grab data from a single row. Specify that row as the parameter.

For example, to get the first row of your result, do this:

```
$this->db->from('view')->where('alias', $alias)->get()->result_array(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only first row as an array you can use this code too:

```
$data = $this->db->from('view')->where('alias', $alias)->get()->first_row('array');
```

But if you really want to get only 1 result, allways use select('TOP 1 ....') because this method improves your query returning time performance. When you use get() directly, it will try to return whole data and not only first row. And then it shows what you want (first row). But if you use TOP 1 method; it's the best.